# Why is my sorting program so slow? (radix/bucket sort in java)

Tags: java, sorting, radix-sort, bucket-sort

This is a radix/bucket sort hybrid that is hard coded for 9 digit numbers. My quicksort program is over twice as fast to sort 10m numbers. I have verified the output is correct, it is just slow.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        inputs.add(in.nextInt());
    }
    radixSort(inputs);
    //System.out.print(toString(radixSort(inputs)));
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> radixSort(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        a = bucketSort(a, i);
    }
    return a;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> bucketSort(ArrayList<Integer> a, int index) {
    // Creates buckets
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> b = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        b.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    // Sorts into buckets
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        b.get(key(a.get(i), index)).add(a.get(i));
    }
    // Concatenates buckets
    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        c.addAll(b.get(i));
    }
    return c;
}

// Takes an integer and index and returns digit at index
public static int key(int num, int ind) {
    int digit = num / (int)Math.pow(10, ind - 1);
    digit = digit % 10;
    return (int)digit;
}

public static String toString(ArrayList<Integer> a){ 
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        s.append(String.format("%09d\n", a.get(i)));
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: I haven't checked the implementation, but that doesn't seem out of the ordinary.  Quick sort is `O(n log(n))` while Radix is `O(wn)`.  For 9 digit numbers, you have `w` of around `29`.  `log(10000000) = 7`, so there's roughly 4 times fewer comparisons going on.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the slowness is appending one integer at a time to each bucket array, having to append again in order to concatenate the buckets, which involve dynamically expanding the arrays.

A counting variation of least significant digit first bucket sort does a one time allocation of a second array the same size as the original array. For the 9 digit example, it could generate counts for the number of occurrences of '0', '1', ... '9', for each digit, then convert the counts into the starting indices for the beginning of each variable sized bucket, eliminating the need for concatenation. For the 9 digit example, a matrix [9][10] could be used for the counts / indices, so only a single pass would be used to generate the matrix.

Wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Example C++ code that sorts an array of 32 bit unsigned integers using byte sized "digits", so the matrix of counts / indices is [4][256]. The only C++ part of this is std::swap(), otherwise it's C code.

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

//  a is input array, b is working array
uint32_t * RadixSort(uint32_t * a, uint32_t *b, size_t count)
{
size_t mIndex[4][256] = {0};            // count / index matrix
size_t i,j,m,n;
uint32_t u;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
        u = a[i];
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u & 0xff)]++;
            u >>= 8;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
        m = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            n = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = m;
            m += n;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // radix sort
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
            u = a[i];
            m = (size_t)(u>>(j<<3))&0xff;
            b[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        std::swap(a, b);                //  swap ptrs
    }
    return(a);
}
```